# Modificar url con htaccess para anteponer variable lang

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hola estoy trabajando con el archivo htaccess, lo que quiero es permitir reescribir la url para anteponer la variable GET lang, sería como lo siguiente

```
Liga actual => como quiero entrar

www.pagina.com/index.php?lang=es&pagina=1 => www.pagina.com/es/index.php?pagina=1
www.pagina.com/index.php?lang=en&pagina=1 => www.pagina.com/en/index.php?pagina=1
www.pagina.com/index.php?lang=de&pagina=1 => www.pagina.com/de/index.php?pagina=1
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score -1):

Encontré la solución!, este código fue el que use en mi archivo htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+\.php)\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/(.+?)/?$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/?$ /?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Lo que hace este código es hacer que esto:

pagina.com/index.php?**lang=es**&pagina=1

sea igual a esto:

pagina.com/**es**/index.php?pagina=1

De esta forma ya puedo enviar la variable GET lang de la siguiente forma en la URL y ya con programación leo la varible lang y cambio el idioma de la página.

```
pagina.com/es/index.php?pagina=1
pagina.com/en/index.php?pagina=1
```

Espero esto le ayude a alguien más :)

Comment: Hola Aagrlp640, sería bueno que incluyas una explicación de cómo esto ayuda a resolver el problema. Esto para que futuros usuarios puedan entender qué están haciendo y resolver el mismo problema o algún problema similar a este.

Comment: Hola, ya hice el cambio, espero haya quedado mejor así la explicación de la solución, perdón no soy muy bueno explicando